# convert more tag to shortcode

Tags: plugins, shortcode

is there is a way to convert `<!-- more -->` to shortcode

Comment: Can you give more details? What do you hope to achieve with this?

Comment: i use a plugin to replace text if a word is found
and want to replace this word with more tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this to your plugin file (or functions.php). You'll use [my_more] as the shortcode for this example.

```
function wpse50449_more_func( $atts ){
 return "\n<!-- more -->\n";
}
add_shortcode( 'my_more', 'wpse50449_more_func' );
```

Comment: not work 
may be it need to replace <!--more--> with call it's function

Comment: That will give you <!--more--> from a shortcode. More information about what you're actually trying to accomplish with this would get you a better answer.

Comment: THX alot i fix it

Comment: Updated your code with prefixing for purposes of best practice. +1